# Can I load adsbygoogle.js only once before head close tag

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have three responsive ads within a page. Every ad unit loads adsbygoogle .jsbefore rendering.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

According to google, I understand I can load adsbygoogle.js **once** instead of three times. Ref: [google's help document](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?vid=0-1360483602128-1512793284086)

My **question** is, can I place a single script tag before head close `</head>`? Or should I include only within the body `<body>` tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Micheal Kleber(Google Engineer)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/HFRhmEhpNrI/IMaTUe9VzUAJ)

> Yes, it is fine to load adsbygoogle.js only once.  That's certainly
>   how I would do it for a web page I was designing: **load it just once
>   from `<head>`**.  It's only included directly in the AdSense snippet to
>   make it as easy as possible for people to copy-and-paste the HTML. 
>   Goran is right that loading it multiple times probably has no
>   perceptible effect on anything, but the duplicate loads are certainly
>   unnecessary and are fine to drop.